# Is the bias form an estimator a real number or we need to define it as a positive number/negative number?

Tags: probability, statistics, statistical-inference, mean-square-error

Is the bias form an estimator a real number or we need to define it as a positive number/negative number? It seems to me that it can be any real number from the following.

From the proof of the variance and bias relationship as [in here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_squared_error), we have that

$$\text{MSE}= \mathbb{V}ar_{\theta}(\hat{\theta})+\text{Bias}^2(\theta,\hat{\theta})$$

By setting $\beta=\text{Bias}(\theta,\hat{\theta})$ and since $\text{MSE}=\mathbb{E}[(\hat{\theta}-\theta)^2]$ we end up with the following

$$\beta=-\sqrt{\mathbb{V}ar_{\theta}(\hat{\theta})-\mathbb{E}[(\hat{\theta}-\theta)^2]},\quad\text{or}\quad \beta=\sqrt{\mathbb{V}ar_{\theta}(\hat{\theta})-\mathbb{E}[(\hat{\theta}-\theta)^2]}$$

it holds that $\mathbb{V}ar_{\theta}(\hat{\theta})\geq\mathbb{E}[(\hat{\theta}-\theta)^2]$. In other words the bias is a real number, right? Or am I missing something?

Is there any suggestion that bias,namely $\beta$, shohld be defined as a positive number and if yes why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual definition of the bias is:
$$\mathrm{Bias}(\hat\theta,\theta) = \mathbb{E}(\hat\theta-\theta)=\mathbb{E}(\hat\theta) - \theta$$
(Note that nothing is squared here.)  So, it is a real number that can be either positive, negative, or zero.  It is positive, if the expected value of the estimator is larger than the the estimand (i.e., the estimator has a positive bias) or negative if it's smaller.  It is zero if the estimator is unbiased, in the sense that its expected value is exactly equal to the estimand.

Comment: thank you very much!